# Wix can't detect changes

Tags: wix, windows-installer

This is my component:

```
 <Component Id="ServiceComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <File Id="ServiceExecutable"
          Name="$(var.LoggerService.TargetFileName)"
          Source="$(var.LoggerService.TargetPath)"
          Vital="yes"
          KeyPath="yes"
          DiskId="1" />
  ...
```

This is my patch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Patch AllowRemoval='yes' Manufacturer='Test Ltd.' MoreInfoURL='www.test.com'
    DisplayName='Test Patch' Description='Small Update Patch' Classification='Update'>

    <Media Id='5000' Cabinet='Patch.cab'>
      <PatchBaseline Id='Sample' />
    </Media>

    <PatchFamilyRef Id="SamplePatchFamily"/>

  </Patch>

  <Fragment>    
    <PatchFamily Id='SamplePatchFamily' Version='1.0.0.0' Supersede='yes'>
      <ComponentRef Id='ServiceComponent' />
    </PatchFamily>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

This is my patch generator script:

```
torch.exe -p -xi bin\Debug\1.1\SetupLogger.wixpdb bin\Debug\1.2\SetupLogger.wixpdb -out diff.wixmst
candle.exe patch.wxs
light.exe patch.wixobj -out patch.wixmsp
pyro.exe patch.wixmsp -out patch.msp -t Sample diff.wixmst
```

If I modify the file `ServiceExecutable` in the same path `$(var.LoggerService.TargetPath)` then Wix doesn't detect any change and saying to me:

```
warning PYRO1079 : The cabinet 'Patch.cab' does not contain any files.  If this patch contains no files, this warning can likely be safely ignored.  Otherwise, try passing -p to torch.exe when first building the transforms, or add a ComponentRef to your PatchFamily authoring to pull changed files into the cabinet.
diff.wixmst : error PYRO0227 : The transform being built did not contain any differences so it could not be created.
```

However, if I modify the file `ServiceExecutable` and put it in the new dir, then specify that new dir in the File source tag, then the change is picked up by Wix and everything is fine.

Question: how can I make Wix to detect the change without changing source path? I think Wix should be able to detect change because the checksum of the `KeyPath` file has been changed.

Comment: WiX patching might expect binaries to be versioned.

Comment: The binaries are versioned indeed